# Sending compiled python file to Telit with C#

Tags: c#, python

I need to send a compiled python file (.pyo extension) over the serial port to my Telit modem with C#. I am writing a C# application to facilitate the downloading of compiled files to the modem. I can successfully send the file to the modem in hyper terminal but I cannot do this from C#.

with C# I can see(AT#LSCRIPT) and delete (AT#DSCRIPT) the files into the modem. so no problem level communication, I think the problem exists in this remark **"The file should be sent using RAW ASCII file transfer"**(because I get ">>>" in the loop).

```
string rst = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\smsp\EV.pyo", Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
sp.Write("AT&K2\r");
Thread.Sleep(500);

sp.Write("AT+IPR=115200\r");
Thread.Sleep(500);

sp.Write("AT#WSCRIPT=\"EV.pyo\",1160,0" + System.Environment.NewLine);
rep = sp.ReadExisting();

while (!rep.Contains(">>>"))
{
    rep = sp.ReadExisting();
}

sp.Write(rst);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the bytes for the ASCII representation of the commands you need to send using the [ASCIIEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(your_command_string);
```

And then send the bytes with the `SerialPort.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
sp.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
```

Check also if the newline character has to be in Windows `\r\n` or Unix `\n` format.

Comment: thanx for response.
I try it but dosn't work.
i changed the line of encoding then it's work

 var utf8bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            var bytes = Encoding.Convert(
                            ;Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"), utf8bytes) 
sp.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);